# How to apply custom shader to sprite in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I want to be able to apply some procedural structures to faces. First task, when I faced such demand is to create billboard, on which is drawn nuclear blast in open space. I hoped to make it as a animated radial gradient and I have succeed partly.

The main thing is for each fragment shader - to have access to `UV` as to uniform var.

Seems like the main thing about rendering sprites - is to access to camera projection matrix in the vertex shader.

Here's example http://goo.gl/A7pY01!

Now I want to draw this onto the billboard sprite. I supposed to use `THREE.Sprite` for this with `THREE.ShaderMaterial`, but had no luck in this. It seemed, that `THREE.SpriteMaterial` is only good material for sprites. And after inspecting some source-code I revealed why Sprites are draw in one special way using plugins.

So, before I found myself  inventing  my own bicycle, I felt needness to ask people how to place my own custom shader on my own custom sprite without hacking THREE.js?

Comment: Good question. Consider rendering your shader to a texture, and then using the texture as the `map` for the `SpriteMaterial`.

Comment: Yep. I think, I will do it somehow in this way, but there's few lacks of this decision. I will definetely reconsider method of rendering a little later. Answera for this question will show how to things in future. (Maybe THREE.js needs some `THREE.ShaderedSpritePlugin` object.. :))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So.
After a small research and work I have considered `THREE.ShaderMaterial` is the best option to complete this little task. Thanks to `/extras/renderers/plugins/SpritePlugin`, I realized how to form and position sprites using vertex shaders. I still have  some question, but I found one good solution.

To accomplish my task, firstly I create a simple plane geometry:

```
 var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );
```

And use it in mesh with `ShaderMaterial`:

```
            uniforms = {
                cur_time: {type:"f", value:1.0},
                beg_time:{type:"f", value:1.0},
                scale:{type: "v3", value:new THREE.Vector3()}
            };

            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                uniforms: uniforms,
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
                transparent: true,
                blending:THREE.AdditiveBlending // It looks like real blast with Additive blending!!!

            } );


 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Here's my shaders:
Vertex shader:

```
        varying vec2 vUv;
        uniform vec3 scale;

        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            float rotation = 0.0;

            vec3 alignedPosition = vec3(position.x * scale.x, position.y * scale.y, position.z*scale.z);

            vec2 pos = alignedPosition.xy;

            vec2 rotatedPosition;
            rotatedPosition.x = cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x - sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
            rotatedPosition.y = sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x + cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;

            vec4 finalPosition;

            finalPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
            finalPosition.xy += rotatedPosition;
            finalPosition = projectionMatrix * finalPosition;

            gl_Position =  finalPosition;

        }
```

I got vertex shader from original Sprite Plugin source code, and changed it slightly.
BTW, changing `+=` to `=` makes sprite screen-sticky. This thing wasted a lot of my time.

And this is my fragment shader:

```
        uniform float cur_time;
        uniform float beg_time;

        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            float full_time = 5000.;

            float time_left = cur_time - beg_time;
            float expl_step0 = 0.;
            float expl_step1 = 0.3;
            float expl_max   = 1.;

            float as0 = 0.;
            float as1 = 1.;
            float as2 = 0.;

            float time_perc = clamp( (time_left / full_time), 0., 1. ) ;
            float alphap; 
            alphap = mix(as0,as1, smoothstep(expl_step0, expl_step1, time_perc));
            alphap = mix(alphap,as2, smoothstep(expl_step1, expl_max, time_perc));


            vec2 p = vUv;
            vec2 c = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
            float max_g = 1.;
            float dist = length(p - c) * 2. ;

            float step1 = 0.;
            float step2 = 0.2;
            float step3 = 0.3;

            vec4 color;
            float a0 = 1.;
            float a1 = 1.;
            float a2 = 0.7;
            float a3 = 0.0;


            vec4 c0 = vec4(1., 1., 1., a0 * alphap);
            vec4 c1 = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 1., a1 * alphap);
            vec4 c2 = vec4(0.7, 0.7, 1., a2 * alphap);
            vec4 c3 = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);



            color = mix(c0, c1, smoothstep(step1, step2, dist));
            color = mix(color, c2, smoothstep(step2, step3, dist));
            color = mix(color, c3, smoothstep(step3, max_g, dist));

            gl_FragColor = color;
   }
```

Here's example of how to make multipoint gradient, animated by time. There's a lot to optimize and several thoughts how to make this even more beautiful.

But this one is almost what I wanted.

Comment: Would be nice to simply be able to attach a shader to a SpriteMaterial - but in the meantime thanks for this, though, very helpful!

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but I miss something... Where is the sprite loaded? Is it inside vertex shader?

Comment: My task was to create dynamic image, positioned in scene like sprite. (Face to viewer, but in scene with size adjusted according to depth). So, I don’t need to load texture. I just needed to calculate correct vertex shader scene size and draw nice gradient on it.